# Setting & Getting Values from ThreadContext in log4j2

Tags: slf4j, log4j2, threadcontext

I am using log4j-api-2.0-beta4.jar along with sl4j in my web-app.
I am trying to insert some values into ThreadContext.

```
ThreadContext.put("user",userName);           ThreadContext.put("thread",thread);
ThreadContext.put("url",url);
```

All I have done to get ThreadContext is to import the class.

At the end of the class, I am doing the following:

```
ThreadContext.clear();
```

The pattern layout that I am using in my log4j2.xml is:

```
<RollingFile name="Default" fileName="${logDir}/${filePrefix}.log"
                 filePattern="${logDir}/${filePrefix}/${filePrefix}.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %37c %X{user} %x %m%n"/>
      <Policies>`enter code here`
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
```

I am not getting any value as part of %X{user} and %x gives me [].
I need to get these values in my log file.
Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I figured it out myself.

It is that the flow is not reaching that part of the code at all ;).

Sorry for the trouble guys, but Thanks anyways.